# Order of the direct product of $\,\Bbb Z/5\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z/5\Bbb Z\,$

Tags: group-theory

I'm feeling quite stupid at the moment.
The direct product $\,\Bbb Z/5\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z/5\Bbb Z\,$ should have order 25, right?

Comment: ofcourse 5x5 25 elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by Z/Z5 you mean $\Bbb Z/5\Bbb Z$, then yes, you are correct. Any time we use a direct product $A\times B$, there will be $|A|\cdot |B|$ elements.

Comment: I wanted to edit the title, but the OP wrote it as Z5. So I stopped.

Comment: @BabakSorouh: I agree, I wasn't sure if this answered his question or not, but I thought it might be worth putting anyway.

Comment: Ah yes sorry, that's what I meant. Thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: @Horstenson: You're welcome.